# Trying to delete data from table, when the ID is not known until the user clicks delete. SQL & PHP

Tags: php, html, css, sql

On my home.php, I have blogs that automatically get added to it when an admin submits a blog from admin.php. However, I am trying to add a delete feature, so that an admin is able to delete a certain blog from home.php, rather than going in the PHPMyAdmin database in order to delete the data from the table.

I have tried different SQL statements and used different variables in order to try an complete this, however none have seemed to work. Some have worked, but not in the right way (as in when the delete button is pressed, it deletes everything rather than the select blog).

PHP & SQL Statement from deletepost.php:

```
$blogid = $_GET['blogid'];
$query= mysqli_query($con, "SELECT blogid FROM blog_post WHERE blogid = '".$blogid."'");
if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){

    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC); // fetch the data
    $query= mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM blog_post WHERE blogid = {$row['blogid']}");
    echo "deleted";

} else {
    echo mysqli_error($con);
}

mysqli_close($con)
```

home.php code:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $count = $count + 1;
        echo "<div class='the-blog'>";
        echo "<h2>".$row['postTitle']."</h2>";
        echo "<h3>Posted by: " . $row['author'] . "</h2>";
        echo "<p>". $row['postCont'] . " </p>";
        if(isset($_SESSION['admin'])){
                              if($_SESSION['admin'] == "admin"){
                                  echo "<form action='deletepost.php'>";
                                  echo "<input id='number' type='number' value=" . $row['blogid'] .">";
                                  echo "<br><input type='submit' value='Delete' name='delete'>";
                                  echo "</form>";
                              }}
        echo "</div>";  
    }
} else {
    echo "<h2 align='center'>Blog Currently Not Available!</h2>";
    }
```

I expect that when the admin clicks the delete button, that it should delete that specific blog. So for example, if the admin clicks the delete button on the most recent blog, then it should only delete that data from the database. If the admin was to click on another blog, such as the 4th blog down then it should delete that specific blog from the database.

Comment: check if query execute or not .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need to `SELECT` before deleting. Simply use the value from the form.

- use *prepared statements* instead of directly injecting user-entered data into your SQL statements.
- use form method *post* instead of *get* for destructive actions.
- use `name='blogid'` in your form to actually send the ID across the wire. This is probably the reason you were deleting everything instead of only the single entry.

home.php

```
<?php
// Notice method is post
if($_SESSION['admin'] == "admin"){
    echo "<form method='post' action='deletepost.php'>";
    echo "<input name='blogid' id='number' type='number' value=" . $row['blogid'] .">";
    echo "<br><input type='submit' value='Delete' name='delete'>";
    echo "</form>";
}}
```

deletepost.php

```
<?php
// Processing script. 
if ($_SESSION['admin'] == "admin") {
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

        $blogid = $_POST['blogid'];

        $stmt = $con->prepare("DELETE FROM blog_post WHERE blogid = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $blogid); // Maybe it is a string? Then, use `s` instead of `i`nteger
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();

        echo "deleted";
    }
}
```

Comment: Based on the form you've provided the code would not work. 1. You're missing the `name` property on your `input`. 2. `$_POST['blogid']` is never passed.

Comment: Ahhh yes... Updating now.